# How to store data of same name in a session in php?

Tags: php, session

I want my user to be able to submit a form, and then those form values are stored in a session.  The form posts back to itself, so how can I store the data time and time again in a session?

```
<form action="addPerson.php" method="post">
    <input required="required" placeholder="Name" name="personname"/>       
    <label for="gender">Male or Female?</label> 
    <select id="gender" name="gender">      
        <option value="f">Female</option>
        <option value="m">Male</option>
    </select>


<button type="submit">add person</button>
</form>
```

So I was thinking:

```
$_SESSION["personname"] = $_POST['personname'];
$_SESSION["persongender"] = $_POST['gender'] ;
```

But this would get replaced every time a new form is posted.

Comment: Is their a prior session used in a userlogin?

Comment: no there is no other session

Comment: multidimensional arrays `$_SESSION[]["personname"] = $_POST['personname'];`

Comment: Remember to do a `session_start()` in all your pages to not lose the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['people'][] = array(
    'personname' => $_POST['personname'],
    'persongender' => $_POST['gender']
);
```

Comment: thanks, so with this would I first of all need to declare the array by doing `$_SESSION['people'][] = array();` before I have any data?  Then when I get data I could simply do `$_SESSION['people']['personname']=> $_POST['personname']`.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes and no. You can actually leave the array creation out. Since `$_SESSION` already is an array, PHP will create any intermediate arrays automatically. It may be good form to initialize it explicitly though.

Comment: This isn't quite right because as soon as I then do `$_SESSION['people']['personname']=> $_POST['personname']` I seem to be overwriting the previous `$_SESSION['people]['personaname`], it's not adding a new index

Comment: Look at my code again. Each entry is `$_SESSION['people'][0]['personname']`, `$_SESSION['people'][1]['personname']` etc.

Comment: what sets that index though?  Is it the empty brackets?

Comment: Yes. `$_SESSION['people']` is an array. `$_SESSION['people'][]` adds a new entry to that array.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$_SESSION["personname"][] = $_POST['personname'];
$_SESSION["persongender"][] = $_POST['gender'] ;
```

The values are stored in an array that way.

Or:

```
$_SESSION['persons'][] = array( $_POST['personname'], $_POST['gender']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

```
$_SESSION[] = array("personname" => $_POST['personname'], 
                    "persongender" => $_POST['gender']) ;
```

This way you get a multidemensional array and you can loop through it if you want to access an old value.